# Subscription Purchase in Unity iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, subscription

My app contains subscription based functionality for purchase. So which way I require to move ahead into this?

When I search for this in Google, I always found **Consumable** and **Non-Consumable** product purchase related help.

I want to move ahead with **Renewable Subscription** purchase. At present I have Prime31 plugin with following source code written:

```
 #if UNITY_ANDROID
     var productId = GameConstants.SKU_PURCHASE_9999_COINS;
     #elif UNITY_IOS
     var productId = GameConstants.SKU_PURCHASE_9999_COINS;
     #endif
     IAP.purchaseConsumableProduct (productId,  (didSucceed, error) => {
         Debug.Log ("purchasing product " + productId + " result: " + didSucceed);
         if (didSucceed) {                    
         }                
     });
```

Whether using same code, Can I use for Subscription purchase? 
What is alternative way for me to implement Subscription purchase?